# Send specific log with specific pharse to my mail

Tags: logs, sendmail, logwatch, kibana

I want to send specific log which has specific phrase to my mail.

For example:

```
ERROR LOG SOMETHING.COM IP XX.XXX.XXX.XXX PORT:2343 Bad XXXXXXX
```

And if upper log has phase `SOMETHING.COM`, send me this log to email.

Is it possible in `logwatch` or `kibana`? Or maybe something else?

Comment: *send me this log* - do you want the whole log file to be sent?

Comment: @Xalorous there’s not much point just editing the title — your edit would be much more useful if you fixed up the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [simple event correlator](https://simple-evcorr.github.io) and a configuration file along the lines of

```
type=SingleWithThreshold
ptype=SubStr
pattern=SOMETHING.COM
desc=SOMETHING.COM
action=pipe '%s' /usr/bin/mail -s 'SOMETHING.COM' jdoe@example.org
window=86400
thresh=1
```

And `sec` told to use the file containing the above against the file that the log appears in (this will vary depending on how `sec` is installed, whether there's a vendor package, etc).

The `window` is rather important unless you like dealing with hundreds or thousands of email messages for each and every log line matched; `sec` has other means of rolling up or summarizing results; see the documentation.